# @RequestMapping doesn't map correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-mapping

My problem is that when I use my annotation `@RequestMapping("/adverts/{id}")` above my CommentController class, I can reach this class using both (i.e): `localhost:8080/adverts/1/comments` and `localhost:8080/comments`. How I can disable reaching `localhost:8080/comments`? Thank you.

```
@RestController
class CommentController {

    private final CommentRepository commentRepository;
    private final AdvertRepository advertRepository;
    private final CommentModelAssembler assembler;

    CommentController(CommentRepository commentRepository, AdvertRepository advertRepository, CommentModelAssembler assembler) {
        this.commentRepository = commentRepository;
        this.advertRepository = advertRepository;
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

    @GetMapping("/adverts/{advertId}/comments")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Comment>> all() {
        List<EntityModel<Comment>> comments =
                commentRepository.findAll().stream()
                        .map(assembler::toModel)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return CollectionModel.of(comments,
                linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }

    @PostMapping("/adverts/{advertId}/comments")
    Comment newComment(@RequestBody Comment newComment) {
        return commentRepository.save(newComment);
    }

    @GetMapping("/adverts/{advertId}/comments/{id}")
    EntityModel<Comment> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Comment comment = commentRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new CommentNotFoundException(id));
        return assembler.toModel(comment);
    }

    @PutMapping("/adverts/{advertId}//comments/{id}")
    Comment replaceComment(@RequestBody Comment newComment,
                          @PathVariable Long id) {
        return commentRepository.findById(id)
                .map(comment -> {
                    comment.setAdvertId(newComment.getAdvertId());
                    comment.setComment(newComment.getComment());
                    return commentRepository.save(comment);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newComment.setId(id);
                    return commentRepository.save(newComment);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/adverts/{advertId}/comments/{id}")
    void deleteComment(@PathVariable Long id) {
        commentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class CommentModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Comment, EntityModel<Comment>> {

    @Override
    public EntityModel<Comment> toModel(Comment comment) {
        return EntityModel.of(comment,
                linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class).one(comment.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                linkTo(methodOn(CommentController.class).all()).withRel("comments"));
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
class UserController {

    private final UserRepository repository;
    private final UserModelAssembler assembler;

    UserController(UserRepository repository, UserModelAssembler assembler) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<User>> all() {
        List<EntityModel<User>> users =
                repository.findAll().stream()
                        .map(assembler::toModel)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return CollectionModel.of(users,
                linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    User newUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        return repository.save(newUser);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    EntityModel<User> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        User user = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));
        return assembler.toModel(user);
    }

    @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    User replaceUser(@RequestBody User newUser,
                     @PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(user -> {
                    user.setName(newUser.getName());
                    user.setRole(newUser.getRole());
                    user.setBoughtVehicles(newUser.getBoughtVehicles());
                    user.setSoldVehicles(newUser.getSoldVehicles());
                    return repository.save(user);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newUser.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newUser);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
class AdvertController {

    private final AdvertRepository repository;
    private final AdvertsModelAssembler assembler;

    AdvertController(AdvertRepository repository, AdvertsModelAssembler assembler) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.assembler = assembler;
    }

    @GetMapping("/adverts")
    CollectionModel<EntityModel<Advert>> all() {
        List<EntityModel<Advert>> adverts =
                repository.findAll().stream()
                .map(assembler::toModel)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return CollectionModel.of(adverts,
                linkTo(methodOn(AdvertController.class).all()).withSelfRel());
    }

    @PostMapping("/adverts")
    Advert newAdvert(@RequestBody Advert newAdvert) {
        return repository.save(newAdvert);
    }

    @GetMapping("/adverts/{id}")
    EntityModel<Advert> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Advert advert = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AdvertNotFoundException(id));
        return assembler.toModel(advert);
    }

    @PutMapping("/adverts/{id}")
    Advert replaceAdvert(@RequestBody Advert newAdvert,
                         @PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id)
                .map(advert -> {
                    advert.setAutoCategory(newAdvert.getAutoCategory());
                    advert.setAutoName(newAdvert.getAutoName());
                    advert.setAutoModel(newAdvert.getAutoModel());
                    advert.setComments(newAdvert.getComments());
                    return repository.save(advert);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newAdvert.setId(id);
                    return repository.save(newAdvert);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/adverts/{id}")
    void deleteAdvert(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

`localhost:8080/comments` result:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "comments" : [ {
      "advertId" : 1,
      "comment" : "That's a nice car!",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/comments/3"
        },
        "comment" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/comments/3"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "advertId" : 2,
      "comment" : "What a nice color of the car!",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/comments/4"
        },
        "comment" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/comments/4"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/comments"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/comments"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete class since there is no cars in your RequestMapping.

Comment: Please add your current code and what you have tried till now.

Comment: I added the CommentController

Comment: can you please explian the word `reach`? cause, they are annotated with different HTTP methods, so that shouldn't be problem

Comment: I wanted to make sure that it is possible to see only each user's comments, not all the possible comments. So using localhost:8080/comments has no point.

Comment: @cjacky475, please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Your `localhost:8080/comments` API seems to come from different controller, not from this one you have posted.

**Update**:
If you want to see only each user's comment, you can change your controller definition following way to make it more generic and simple:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/adverts")
class CommentController {
```

**Update 2:**
You need to update your controller-url mapping. Generally, we define a common url-name for a specific controller/purpose. Like for your  `CommonController` you can do this:

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/common")
    class CommentController {
```

See the name `/commom`. Then, under this controller, you add other API like `/comments/all`, `/comments/{id}`, `/comments/others`. To access these controller method, you must follow this hierarchy like:
`/common/comments/all` or `/common/comments/1`
Similarly for AdvertController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/advert")
class AdvertController {
```

Again, check the common url-name `/advert`. API under this controller will have naming like this:
`/all`, '/{id}'. To access this controller method use URL this way:
`/advert/all`, `/advert/1`
This should clear your idea.
One thing, I have excluded the base-url `localhost:8080` part from the url-example I have shown, mind adding this.
Hope, this will server your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But by removing {id} wouldn't I need to add this {id} above after every method in my class to get specific user's comments, or to add comment to user? And none of my others controller neither request nor get any mapping associated with comments. How can other controller open /comments? Thank you.

Comment: you have to pass {id} for every API which has that as pathVariable like these:
`/adverts/comments/1` --for specific user-to add or delete or get, `adverts/comments` --for all users and so on. This is standard way

Comment: I added my all controllers. But I can't do /adverts/comments/1, because I do not specify specific advert, can I?

Comment: Thank you for your response once again. Actually I pretty much understand the hierarchy principle and that's what I wanted to achieve by adding /adverts/{id} above my CommentController. I wanted to achieve this hierarchy: /adverts/1/comments or /adverts/1/comments/2 to show specific advert's all comments or specific comment. The problem is the same: I can access all the comments by /comments but I pretty much declared the RequestMapping("/adverts/{id}") to reach all comments. I am sorry If I can't clearly explain my problem.

Comment: First of all, I don't see any reason to redirect you to all the comments API using `/comments` as this is not even defined. Secondly, it is not a good design to use pathvariable at top of the class. Can you confirm where does your `localhost:8080/comments` request redirect by using debugger or printing the log? And better if you remove the pathvariable from top of the class, instead use in the method level

Comment: Sorry for late response. I updated my post. Would you mind checking my changed CommentController. Is this the good design by removing top pathvariable and moving at the top of the methods? I included my results what I get after typing `localhost:8080/comments`. Would this confirm your question about redirection? And I'm not sure how does `localhost:8080/comments` work, since I do not define it anywhere. Hope you will help me.

Comment: TBH, it seems very strange in your case you are facing. did you debug step by step in which controller `localhost:8080/comments` hits? Please do it first. Moreover, if you have simplified version of your project , please provide a github link so that I can check my myself

Comment: I found the problem but not sure how to fix it. It is my repositories extends JpaRepository.